# Why is this question being downvoted?

Tags: discussion, voting

[This question about playing & recording Minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/120582/what-are-the-recomended-system-requirments-to-screen-record-minecraft-with-mediu) (and the required specs) is being downvoted, and I don't know why - it's not my question, but I'm pretty sure knowing the problems within it will help me in the future.

There are plenty of [other questions about system requirements](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=system%20requirements) which have positive votes.

So, **what are the reasons/possible reasons [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/120582/what-are-the-recomended-system-requirments-to-screen-record-minecraft-with-mediu) is being downvoted?**

Comment: I didn't downvote the question (I also didn't vote to close the question either) however this isn't a question about the minimum specs to run Minecraft, this is a question about the minimum specs to run screen capture software

Comment: Probably because it doesn't make much sense, there aren't minimum specs to record something in such a broad sense -- no specifics were given about the tools, resolution, codec, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The question is essentially a buying recommendation in disguise.  "Is my computer good enough to record?" is pretty much the same as "What computer do I need to buy in order to record?"  Additionally, this question will only be good for ~6 months until new hardware is released.  While the min specs might not change much for Minecraft, if we were to generalize the question to new games, it'd change basically every month (especially since PC gamers are expecting some big leaps with regards to graphics in the near future, given the upcoming console releases).

Also, there are a whole host of things to consider beyond the software and hardware of the computer: What resolution do you want to record at?  What frame rate?  What are you doing with the video after you record it?  Are you planning on streaming while recording?  How much do you care about the video quality of the final product? (which is highly subjective, BTW.)  Without this information (and possibly more), the question isn't very constructive.  With them, it can quickly become too localized.

Finally, even with the specs listed (which wasn't much), and all the above questions answered, the best anyone would be able to do is say "probably".  In the end, you're not going to know how good your recordings are going to be until you record something.

Comment: If this is the case, why is it not being closed as too localized/off topic?

Comment: @AliceRees: "this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion."  It's not a perfect fit, which is part of the reason why we're getting new close reasons in the coming weeks.  Also, we're not big fans of too localized, and indeed this question (as it currently stands) really isn't.  It's also not off-topic, since it's about a video game (albeit indirectly).

Answer (score 8):

I downvoted it. For various reasons.

The first such reason is that the question lacks data - what recording software? What settings? What graphics card is it now? I quote: "one of the higher AMD graphics cards (Not Sure Which One Though)" - that's not helpful whatsoever here.

Secondly, I personally find the very idea of "minimum specs" to *record gameplay* rather pointless. You can give rules of thumb, you can give rough estimates - what you can't give, that's a definitive answer other than "For me, X worked".

Comment: Not to mention hard drive write speed can easily be the confounding factor.